# CakePHP - Class 'AuthComponent' not found in cached view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP 2.3. and I'm trying to cache my home page view. But After caching
it to home.php, I can't load cached view because of error:

```
Error: Class 'AuthComponent' not found
File: C:\wamp\www\project\trunk\app\tmp\cache\views\home.php
Line: 87
```

I use AuthComponent for realizing if user is logged in or not. Without caching Everything works.

Controller code:

public $helpers = array('Cache');

```
public $cacheAction = array(
   'home' => '60 minutes',
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

App::uses() your Auth component in your bootstrap would help:

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
```

This way Cake knows where to load the class from if its needed (even in cache mode).

Answer (score 0):

That would be this line in the file \config\bootstrap.php

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
```

Note that I tried this in Cake 4.1.5 but it tlls me "Class 'AuthComponent' not found"